# Draw a circle to highlight a curve's maximum in R

Tags: r, plot, graph

I'm trying to draw a little circle to highlight the maximum of a function plotted with the `curve()` method. I already know the coordinates of the point, so it isn't necessary to compute them with R.
This is the code I've written to draw the curve:

```r
curve(expr=exp(-((sum(s1, s2, s3, s4, s10, s599)-x*1599)^2)/
                 (2*1599*x))/sqrt(2*pi*1599*x), xlim=c(0.5, 1.5), 
      xlab=expression("rate"~~"[ "*s^-1*" ]"), ylab="")
```

I also attach a pair of images of what I have and what I'd like to do.

The curve I can draw:
[image]

The curve with the little circle:
[image]

I thank you all in advance for any help you will give.

Lorenzo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `points`.

***Example:***

```
curve(x^2)
points(x=.5, y=.25, cex=2, col="red")
```

[image]

Or, more sophisticated...

```
v <- curve(-x^2, xlim=c(-1, 1))
points(max(v$y), v$x[which.max(v$y)], cex=2, col=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option to find the location of the maximum a bit more precisely than `which.max` is to use `optimize`.

```
y = function(x,s=2000) exp(-((s-x*1599)^2)/(2*1599*x))/sqrt(2*pi*1599*x)
xlim = c(0.5, 1.5)

curve(y, xlim=xlim)

maximum = optimize(y, xlim, maximum = TRUE)
points(maximum$maximum, maximum$objective, col='red')
```

[image]